# Return a string from a method in C#

Tags: c#, string, class, methods, return

I am trying to return a string from the `SalesPerson` object with `fullNameMethod` to the main program, but this isn't working. What am I doing wrong?

```
class SalesPerson
{
    string firstName, lastName;
    public string FirstName { get { return firstName; } set { firstName = value; } }
    public string LastName { get { return lastName; } set { lastName = value; } }

    public SalesPerson(string fName, string lName)
    {
        firstName = fName;
        lastName = lName;
    }

    public string fullNameMethod()
    {
        string x = firstName + " " + lastName;
        return x;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SalesPerson x = new SalesPerson("john", "Doe");
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", x.fullNameMethod);
    }
}
```

Comment: The code doesn't even compile. You have a syntax error on the line with `Console.WriteLine`.

Comment: On a side note, `fullNameMethod` should be using the public properties, not the private fields, and using the word `method` in a method name is a bit, er, redundant.

Comment: Looks like your new to programming. You cannot access methods like that. Let me see if I can give an an answer using your code but reformatted properly

Comment: Yes, and if it is a method, call it with braces: `Console.WriteLine("{0}",x.fullNameMethod());`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're currently trying to access a method like a property

```
Console.WriteLine("{0}",x.fullNameMethod);
```

It should be

```
Console.WriteLine("{0}",x.fullNameMethod());
```

Alternatively you could turn it into a property using

```
public string fullName
{
   get
   {
        string x = firstName + " " + lastName;
        return x;
   }
}
```

Comment: yes this is what i should be doing Console.WriteLine("{0}",x.fullNameMethod());
thanks alot

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the () at the end. It is not a variable, but a function and when there are not parameters, you still need the () at the end.

For future coding practices, I would highly recommend reforming the code a little bit as this can become frustrating to read:

```
 public string LastName
 { get { return lastName; } set { lastName = value; } }
```

If there is any kind of processing which happens in here (thankfully doesn't happen here), it will become very confusing. If you're going to pass your code onto someone else, I would recommend:

```
public string LastName
{
  get
  {
     return lastName;
  }
  set
  {
     lastName = value;
  }
}
```

It's a lot longer, but it's much easier to read when glancing at a huge section of code.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to have a method for that. You could create a property like this instead:

```
class SalesPerson
{
    string firstName, lastName;
    public string FirstName { get { return firstName; } set { firstName = value; } }
    public string LastName { get { return lastName; } set { lastName = value; } }
    public string FullName { get { return this.FirstName + " " + this.LastName; } }
}
```

The class could even be shortened to:

```
class SalesPerson
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FullName { 
       get { return this.FirstName + " " + this.LastName; } 
    }
}
```

The property could then be accessed like any other property:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SalesPerson x = new SalesPerson("John", "Doe");
        Console.WriteLine(x.FullName); // Will print John Doe
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `x.fullNameMethod()` to call the method.

Answer (score -2):

These answers are all *way* too complicated!

The way he wrote the method is fine. The problem is where he invoked the method. He did not include parentheses after the method name, so the compiler thought he was trying to get a value from a variable instead of a method.

In Visual Basic and [Delphi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embarcadero_Delphi), those parentheses are optional, but in C#, they are required. So, to correct the last line of the original post:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0}", x.fullNameMethod());
```

Comment: Turning `Console.WriteLine("{0}",x.fullNameMethod);` to `Console.WriteLine("{0}",x.fullNameMethod());` is exactly what the accepted answer says.